# Why does multithreading make my Conway's Game of Life slower?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I'm currently making Conway's Game of Life in c++ with visualization in sfml. I tried to add multithreading in order to improve performance.

Code responsible for creating threads:

```
        vector<vector<int>> tempBoard(HEIGHT, vector<int>(WIDTH, 0));
        vector<thread> threads;
        for (int x = 0; x < THREAD_COUNT; x++) {
            thread toAdd(turn, ref(board), ref(tempBoard), x);
            threads.push_back(move(toAdd));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
        board = tempBoard;
```

Function that my threads are executing:

```
void turn(vector<vector<int>>& board, vector<vector<int>>& tempBoard, int threadNum) {

    int start = ((float)threadNum) / THREAD_COUNT * WIDTH;
    int end = (((float)threadNum + 1) / THREAD_COUNT) * WIDTH;

    for (int x = start; x < end; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            int alive = aliveNeighbours(x, y, board);
            if (alive < 2 or alive > 3) {
                tempBoard[y][x] = 0;
            }
            else if (board[y][x] == 0 and alive == 3) {
                tempBoard[y][x] = 1;
            }
            else if (board[y][x] == 1) {
                tempBoard[y][x] = 1;
            }
            else {
                tempBoard[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be causing the slow-down? Is it related to the fact that all of my threads need access to `tempBoard`?

Comment: It looks like you are starting and stopping your threads each iteration. This is generally a costly and slow operation, it may outweigh the benefits you get from parallelizing the work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I measured the execution time of the ```turn``` function for each of the threads - it's still slower than singlethreaded solution. This implies that thread creation is not the issue, or at least not a big part of it.

Comment: Your access order is inefficient: since you change the outer index often, and the second one less often, this means the compiler cannot optimize the code here by retrieving a reference to the inner vector first and then using this in the inner loop. This also means that the values accessed have a good chance of being stored on separate memory pages and this concurrent access to many memory locations could result in trouble for the cache. Also note that there's an overhead for creating&joining threads; the problem may not be large enough to yield a speedup in this scenario...

Comment: You probably should not use a `vector<vector<int>>`, but instead use a `vector<int>` of size height * width as a member of a class Board object, and figure out the x,y location within the 1D flattened representation of the 2D matrix.

Comment: Additionally to other comment, consider using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back(move(...))` although this is a minor points compared to others. By the way, [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) can speed this process up by a large margin: certainly from 10 to 100 times faster on mainstream modern processors and bit arrays, which is much more than multithreading could do (unless you use very expensive high-end recent server processors). Also, please do not use `int` (usually 32 or 64 bits wide) to store a boolean value (which can be stored in 1 bit): this is a huge wast of space.

Comment: You might be copying over the entire matrix, every iteration. Even if it's actually a move, you are still allocating, initializing and deleting an entire matrix for every iteration.  Use std::swap to flip between the live and temp boards, and make sure there's only one temp board for the entire run.